# Derechos de autor lottiefiles

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flutter

Muy buenas compañeros tengo una duda estoy realizando un proyecto en android y es la primera vez que la publicare en la play store y estoy haciendo uso de varias animaciones existentes en  http://lottiefiles.com/ mi pregunta es si no hay problema al subir la app a la play store con derechos de autor o algo por el estilo ? Agradezco mucho sus respuestas y consejos

Comment: Qué licencia tienen tales animaciones? Utilizas código o reimplementas la idea?

Comment: Los creadores deben ser atribuidos en su aplicación. Esta atribución debe ser visible para el usuario final. LottieFiles recomienda que la atribución se coloque en la sección Acerca de, Licencias. Ejemplo: @shafiu / LottieFiles eso esta en la pagina en mi app tendria que tener un apartado para las licencias o como seria?

Comment: De hecho si tiene que ser visible lo debes incluir en la misma página en usas la animación.

Comment: En el menú puedes crear una opción "Acerca de" que haga referencia a "Términos de uso", "Políticas de datos", "Licencias", etc, en el cual por ejemplo al seleccionar esta opción te muestre un POP-UP con las atribuciones correspondientes. **Cómo hacer la atribución**
Haz referencia al titulo, al autor, fuente y la licencia. **Ejemplo:**
Animación del gato bailando por Mario Remiré bajo la licencia CC BY 2.0 De seguro te interesara leer estas buenas practicas sobre [atribución](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Es:Mejores_pr%C3%A1cticas_para_atribuci%C3%B3n).

Comment: muchas gracias por el consejo

Comment: Me parece que en este sitio específicamente al realizar la compra puedes obtener la licencia de uso.